# TFS - How to carry on working on file which has pending check in changes?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I have shelved my changes in TFS which will be checked in few days time. Now i want to work on different TFS card which belongs to same file. How can i work on the same file when its changes are not checked in yet ?

Comment: How about the issue, is there anything to update?

Answer (score 0):

> How can i work on the same file when its changes are not checked in yet ?

You should use [Branch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/manage-your-branches?view=azure-devops). You can create a new branch based on file are not checked in, then you work on different TFS card with previous branch, after that, you can check out the new branch to work on the same file when its changes are not checked in.

Shelvesets are per-user and differently stored in the source control - it is not possible to merge shelvesets, there's no history etc. The only action possible is unshelving; you cannot even merge files while doing so. So, we only use it as a temporary storage for things that are not finished yet and thus cannot be checked into a branch.

So, you should use branches. Maybe a Main branch and different development branches for features & bug fix.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Leo, you can indeed merge on unshelve (it wasn't working in 2010) but they fixed this since 2012.  I do agree on the branching.